# Property Preserving Graph Transformations / Improving Computational Efficiency Through Transformations

Tags: graph-theory

I'll start this off by saying that I am relatively new to graph theory so please point out if this question violates any fundamental ideas within the topic.

I am curious about the general idea of transforming a graph into a new structure such that certain properties of the original graph are preserved.  I have found it difficult to find any information on this topic as I likely do not know the right terms to search, or where to do so.

Consider an arbitrary (possibly negatively) weighted directed *cyclic* graph **G**, with elements {G<sub>1</sub>, ..., G<sub>n</sub>}, with edge weights, W = {W<sub>1</sub>, ..., W<sub>m</sub>}.  Is it possible to generate a transformation (or algorithm) **T**: **G** -> **G'**, where **G'** is a directed *acyclic* graph such that one can guarantee some desired property about **G** is preserved in **G'**, while making no claims about other properties?

Ex. if the shortest path from G<sub>a</sub> to G<sub>b</sub> is P = (G<sub>a</sub>->G<sub>c</sub>->G<sub>b</sub>), then the shortest path from G'<sub>a</sub> to G'<sub>b</sub> is P' = (G'<sub>a</sub>->G'<sub>c</sub>->G'<sub>b</sub>) or if the sum of edge weights in P is negative then the same is true for P'.

To be most specific, I am trying interested in transforms such that some algorithm to solve for a desired condition (like shortest path, or negatively weighted path) in **G** is faster when applied to **G'**.

Is this possible? What properties could this hold true for and on which classes of graphs?

I understand that a complete solution to this (like proving existence for any graph / any property) is likely impossible as it would in effect solve P=NP. I am interested in any sort of heuristics / approximations that can be made here rather than exact solutions, and am interested in any further reading (e.g. ML techniques).

Comment: This question seems to broad. There are such examples, like the condensed graph or a quotient graph (in the sense of covering spaces), and both are examples of quotient objects in the category of graphs.